# Getting rotation axis from initial and final rotated quaternions

Tags: c#, 3d, rotation, quaternions

I have to find the axis and angle of rotation of a camera with an UP and Direction vector(They both are perpendicular to each other). I have the initial and final positions of the UP and direction vectors of the camera that is rotated. I want to find the axis and angle of the rotation for the camera. I am using C# for my project. I am new to this 3D rotation. So pardon my questions if you find them silly.

Answer (score 0):

From the direction (forward) vector *f* and up vector *u* you can get the side vector *s* by performing a [vector cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Computing_the_cross_product) (*s = f x u*). All three vectors are now orthogonal. You should also make them orthonormal by normalizing each one of them. Taken together, these vectors form an orthonormal basis.

You now have two such basis: the one from your initial camera orientation and the one from your final camera orientation. Both basis can be represented as a rotation matrix. A rotation matrix is simply a 3x3 matrix where the 3 rows are respectively:

1. The forward vector
2. The up vector
3. The side vector

For example, the matrix:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```

could be your initial camera orientation at start-up with its forward vector, up vector and side vector pointing towards the positive x axis, y axis and z axis, respectively.

You can now convert these two basis (M1 and M2) to two unit quaternions (Q1 and Q2) using this [algorithm](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm) which takes care about potential problems like divides by zero.

At this point, you have two unit quaternions representing your initial and final camera orientation. You must now find the quaternion qT that transforms Q1 into Q2, that is:

```
q2 = qT * q1
q2 * q1^-1 = qT * (q1 * q1^-1) = qT
=> qT = q2 * q1^-1
```

Knowing that the inverse of a unit quaternion is equal to its [conjugate](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuaternionConjugate.html):

```
q1^-1 = q1*    iif  ||q1|| = 1
qT = q2 * q1^-1 = q2 * q1*
```

There is a single step left: [extracting the axis and angle from quaternion](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/index.htm) qT:

```
angle = 2 * acos(qw)
x = qx / sqrt(1-qw*qw)
y = qy / sqrt(1-qw*qw)
z = qz / sqrt(1-qw*qw)
```

The angle is, of course, given in radian. Beware of the divide by zero when calculating x, y and z. This situation would happen when there is no rotation or a very small one, so you should test if angle > epsilon where you would choose epsilon to be quite small an angle (say 1/10 of a degree) and not calculate the vector if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. That really helped me a lot. I have one small problem with the algorithm to convert the matrix to quaternion. My software camera generates some up and direction vectors which is giving a trace of the matrix less than one. When the trace of the rotated matrix is less than one, the rotation axis and angle calculations are giving weird values. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: See function at line 238: http://java.net/projects/vecmath/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/javax/vecmath/AxisAngle4f.java?rev=144
Please check this answer as appropriate if it solves your problem.